# Can manifest heretics be occult non-heretics?

Tags: catholicism, heresy

Can manifest [heretics](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=33904) be [occult](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=35229) non-heretics?

Comment: What's a "manifest" heretic?

Comment: @curiousdannii The opposite of an occult heretic. A manifest heretic makes his heresy public, known to others.

Comment: We may need to define what "is" is here.

Comment: @DanFefferman What do you mean?

Comment: It was meant as a joke referring to an infamous  [saying of Bill Clinton](https://slate.com/news-and-politics/1998/09/bill-clinton-and-the-meaning-of-is.html). Here I think it depends on who is using the verb "be", and whether the manifest heretic knows they are a heretic or not - plus, who defines "heresy."

Comment: Downvoters, please explain your down-votes.

Comment: If you hadn't provided a self-answer, this would probably be closed as unclear. It's not clear why anyone would ask this question. What intellectual quandary prompted it? Just like on SO it's common to include "what have you tried" in the question body, here it's a good idea to include "why do you care" or "what were you studying/experiencing that led to this question". Similarly, if your answer was answering someone else's question rather than your own, it would probably be deleted as a link-only answer or as a low quality answer. Nothing is explained, so the value of this page is dubious.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, if he is a [material heretic](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=33904) (and not a [formal heretic](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=33904)).